# Get a json file's data without using require with a variable as path

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get some data from a `JSON` file, but I can't use require because I need the path to be a variable and if I try to use require with a variable I get an error:

> invalid call

Here is the function :

```
async fetchData(dataPath){
    require(dataPath);
    return data;
}
```

The `dataPath` variable is dependent on a selected button.

Comment: You could use RNFS https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs.  That way you could just read whatever files you wanted either from the bundle or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hey since its static data could you simply make an object of all possibilities

```js
const allPossibleData = {
  customData1: require('./pathToData1'),
  customData2: require('./pathToData2')
}
```

and simply get data by allPossibleData['customData1'], since dynamic require with a variable is not possible otherwise, you can simply do it like this

```js
fetchData(require('dataPath'))
```

and on function instead getting dataPath as rgument simply get data.

Comment: Hello, it's not really static data, but can I simply add to "allPossibleData" every time I need to?

Comment: What do you mean by is not static data? In your question you said  **get some data from a JSON file** so it would be static, do you refer to a path online?

Comment: No, sorry I'm lacking communication skills, what I mean is, there are a bunch of JSONs, and the one I want to use depends. also, the number of JSON files will increase over time

Comment: If you have multiple JSON files why you do not store them in the server? In this case, the require problem disappears.

Comment: I'll swap that data to asyncStorage later, but needed some hardcoded data to test the app, I guess I'll use your solution for now and the swap to asyncstorage earlier

Comment: How about firebase :) its really easy and quick configuration and you'll get real async flow :)
If my post was helpfull please upvote!